# Using multiple connection vs single connections in sql python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, flask, pymysql

I am using pymysql to connect to sql like this:

```py
con=pymysql.connect(...)
cur=con.cursor()
```

Well I am using flask web framework for some use. I defined the connection object as a single time and pass it to other function for use like this:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur.execute(...)
    con.commit()

    #other stuffs
```

My questions is that whether it is a good way or this:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    con=pymysql.connect(...)
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute(...)
    con.commit()

    #other stuffs
```

What should I choose using a single connection or multiple one for every function. I don't want to make it crash if two requests are made at the same time, stop data from corruption and make it synchronised too.
What's actually a good way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one connection.  You can create multiple cursors from that connection, and the cursors will keep different requests separated.

Comment: Thanks, would one cursor if abruptly stopped block the connection for other cursors?

Comment: There's no such thing as "abruptly stopping" a cursor.  A cursor is basically just a position in a query.  If you close a cursor, the others keep their position.

Comment: well i had an issue when having multiple threads using the same connection. at some point in my script threads get stuck. I don't seem to be the only one having this problem as this have been solved with connection pool, there is actually one that can be installed with pip. Based on it i created a personalized one  that better fits my needs. and since i never got threads stuck again.